# Uncompress the gZiped return of Asynchronous Request

Tags: ios, httprequest

I work on iOs and I didn't find the answer anywhere.

The symfony api, on which I work, **gZip** now its response.

How I can **uncompress the responseData** ?

-- EDIT --
Without use file and without know the size of unziped file.

Best regards,

Comment: You mean you want to unzip a file?

Comment: No unzip a NSData, without file ...

Comment: unzip NSData? Please clear your point.

Comment: I think it's clear enough ... For accelerate the data sending between the remote server and my iOS and android applications, the server gZip the response before send the response back.
In Android app, it's one line to uncompress the response, in iOS, I receive the data from an Asynchronous Request and I wonder how uncompress it without temporary file or the knowledge of size of unzip file.
(PS: I've a very bad english, so if you didn't understand a sentance, say it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm just finding a solution.

It's a very usefull **class extension of NSData** here :
http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSDataCategory

Very easy to use, but a little bit tricky to install because a library is required.